# Do I need to control the execution of these two threads with the main threads?

Tags: java, executorservice, callable

```
void process(String question){

                    Callable<ResponseList> callable1 = () -> this.stsCompute question);
                    Future<ResponseList>task1 = executorService.submit(callable1);

                    Callable<ResponseList> callable2 = () -> this.dssmCompute(question);
                    Future<ResponseList>task2 = executorService.submit(callable2);

                    try{
                        ResponseList stsResponse = task1.get();
                        ResponseList dssmResponse = task2.get();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Do I need to wait until the first 2 threads complete?
                    processResponse(stsResponse, dssmResponse);
}
```

In this "process" method, I have two additional threads 'callable1' & 'callable2' to concurrently execute. I want to make sure only when these two tasks complete, the method in the main thread 'processResponse()' can start to be executed.

In such a case, do I need to add any additional control to ensure the order of the execution, is it already good enough? If not, how to make that control happen?

Comment: What happens when you test it? What does the javadoc of Future.get() say?

Comment: "The get() doc says waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result." This doesn't help too much for the time relationship between the 3 threads.

Comment: Well, yes, it does. It literally says: *Waits [...] for the computation to complete*. And you want to *make sure only when these two tasks complete, the method in the main thread 'processResponse()' can start to be executed*. Given that you're calling get() on the two futures before calling processResponse(), and given that get() waits until the tasks are completed, what you're doing does make sure that processResponse() doesn't start executing before the two tasks are completed.

Comment: I agree with JB Nizet, but please be aware that processResponse can be executed when task1 throws an exception and task2 is still executing.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet and Donat. That's great.

Comment: @JBNizet, since the method 'process' has to be called repeatedly, is this a normal way to achieve concurrency in Java? Does it create lots of overhead due to the fact that each call to 'process' will cause the creation and destroy of the two future objects? My original purpose is to speed up my program, and I hope it won't slow down due to the countless creation and destroy of the threads.

Comment: @Donat, JBNizet, just realized that in my code above, are the two tasks executed concurrently, or task2 actually occur AFTER task1? Because the 'get()' method waits, does they run simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Java8+ i would suggest use Completable Futures. It supports exactly the use case you are trying to achieve.

Completable Futures: [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Sample Algorithm looks like:

var cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> processQuestion()).runAsync(() -> processResponse)

**Note:** var is typeInference supports in java 10+

Also, there are plenty of Examples on Completable Futures

Comment: " since the method 'process' has to be called repeatedly, is this a normal way to achieve concurrency in Java? Does it create lots of overhead due to the fact that each call to 'process' will cause the creation and destroy of the two future objects? My original purpose is to speed up my program, and I hope it won't slow down due to the countless creation and destroy of the threads."

Comment: Hi, Anvesh, how about my concern above?

Comment: @User697911 You can use Executor service to pass for CompletableFutures to make sure threads wont be created than the count you specify. 

Also think of using allOf()

Ex: https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Comment: I defined "private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);" as an instance variable of the class in which 'process is defined'. So only one 'ExecutorService' is called, but 'Callable' are created and destroyed repeatedly because 'process' is called repeatedly.

Comment: @user697911 sounds good. you can use more Completable futures instead of callable and then use allOf(). Also, if those callable Future you are using are not bounded to any http calls or io operations and is just for processing internally on application. There is no worry about number of threads they should be really fast in completing process. I am not really sure about your use case of each callable you are creating. Personally i use a lot of completable futures in async way and is able to handle peak load on my application.

Comment: That killed my concern. Thanks.

Comment: please take a look at my questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138500/are-these-two-tasks-executed-concurrently

Answer (score 1):

You should use ExecutorService.invokeAll which will return List of Futures when complete. Besides I would use a shorter syntax, something like

```
 List<Future> futures = executorService.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(()->dssmCompute(), ()->dssmCompute()));
```

Comment: In the returned List, how do I know which future is produced by which method? Are they alined with the array index?

Comment: API says Returns:a list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list.