# Are these two tasks executed concurrently?

Tags: java, completable-future, concurrent.futures

```
CompletableFuture<ResponseList> stsTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.stsCompute(question);
CompletableFuture<ResponseList> dssmTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.dssmCompute(question);

// Is this line unnecessary?
CompletableFuture<Void> twoFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(stsTask, dssmTask);

try {
     ResponseList stsList = stsTask.get();
     ResponseList dssmList = dssmTask.get();

     // after the two are done, proceed here
     processResult(stsList, dssmList)
} catch(Exception e){
    // do something
}
```

**I have two questions:**

1. Are these two tasks executed concurrently? Or the stsTask must be executed before dssmTask due to the `get()` method to wait it for completion? The variable 'twoFutures' is not used.
2. Is the line `CompletableFuture.allOf(stsTask, dssmTask)` unnecessary or necessary?

Comment: Sounds like you dont care about return value of procesResult then why do you want to use Get? This will block threads. There is no real use of completable futures here. Also instead of get use join() which is also blocking but cleaner approach with no try catch. I would say allOf().join().run(()-> processResult)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't invoke `get` on the `twoFutures` that line is redundant.

If you want to wait on both of them to finish and then do something with the results, you should refactor your code as follows:

```
stsTask.thenAcceptBoth(dssmTask, (stsResult, dssmResult) -> {
    ResponseList stsList = stsResult; // or stsTask.get()
    ResponseList dssmList = dssmResult; // or dssmTask.get()
    // ...     
});
```

Comment: I want the stsTask and dssmTask to execute concurrently to speed up. That is the main purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are executed concurrently if you have enough threads in your common fork/join pool. The `allOf` method returns a new `CompletableFuture` that is completed when all of the given `CompletableFutures` complete. But you don't get any facility to merge the result, hence it is not needed here.

Another point to consider here is that the invocation of `future.get()` method to get the result. This method call is blocking and will keep your calling thread in blocking state.

So here's a better way of doing it,

```
stsTask.thenCombine(dssmTask, (stsList, dssmList) -> processResult(stsList, dssmList));
```

Answer (score -1):

use logger when you not sure about the multithread task execution path:

```
    private static Logger logger = getLogger(S.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        CompletableFuture<List> stsTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            logger.info("running");
            return new ArrayList();
        });
        CompletableFuture<List> dssmTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            logger.info("running");
            return new ArrayList();
        });

        // Is this line unnecessary?
        CompletableFuture<Void> twoFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(stsTask, dssmTask);

        logger.info("twoFutures is completed? " + twoFutures.isDone());
        logger.info("allof dose not wait task to complete, just to check if all the task is completed, so this is unnecessary");


        try {
            List stsList = stsTask.get();
            logger.info("stsList completed? " + stsTask.isDone());
            List dssmList = dssmTask.get();
            logger.info("dssmList completed? " + dssmTask.isDone());

            logger.info("get() will block until task is done");

            // after the two are done, proceed here
//          processResult(stsList, dssmList)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do something
        }







    }
```

outPut:

```
15:18:28.791 [main] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - twoFutures is completed? false
15:18:28.791 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - running
15:18:28.791 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - running
15:18:28.794 [main] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - allof dose not wait task to complete, just to check if all the task is completed, so this is unnecessary
15:18:28.795 [main] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - stsList completed? true
15:18:28.795 [main] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - dssmList completed? true
15:18:28.795 [main] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - get will block until task is done
```

I use logback logger, by default it will print thread name, which is convenient for this question.

1. task is executed concurrently, there are two thread running it

   `15:18:28.791 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - running
   15:18:28.791 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO cn.lihongjie.S - running`
2. `allOf` is unnecessary, this call not block until all the task completed. you can figure out by looking at log.

Comment: So they are actually executed concurrently? so i don't need to make any modification

Comment: @user697911 yes